# Regular expression to obtain string before first forward slash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to get *EUR* from *EUR/GBP*

```
$s = 'EUR/GBP'
preg_match('//', $s, $matches);
$s = $matches[0];
```

This currently returns nothing.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Ummm....`$s` isn't a string.  Regular expressions match against strings.  In fact, I really don't know what `$s` is supposed to represent here.

Comment: Do you really need a regular expression here? I think you should do better with `substr` and `strpos` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use 'explode' instead of regular expressions.

```
$values = explode('/', 'EUR/GBP');
echo $values['0']; // EUR
```

Comment: Let's not use effing `explode` for everything, okay? PHP has `strtok` for precisely that.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your string wasn't wrapped with quotes
2. Your regular expression was empty
3. You weren't accessing the correct array index

```
$s = 'EUR/GBP';
preg_match('/([^\/]+)/', $s, $matches);
$s = $matches[1];
```

However, for this situation, using a function like [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) might be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$parts = explode('/', $s);

Array
(
    [0] => EUR
    [1] => GBP
)
```